# Java swing gui program with keylisteners that does not work in linux

Tags: java, swing, raspberry-pi

I have programmed a basic control pad gui in java. When a arrow key is pressed a text will show which button is pressed on the keyboard and a button will change color.

The problem is that this program works fine in windows, but when i try it on my raspberry pi that runs a version of linux called raspbian, this does not seem to work. When i press a button the program does not do anything.

```
package finalRobotControl;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.Listener;

public class Main implements KeyListener{
    public static JButton buttonLeft;
    public static JButton buttonRight;
    public static JButton buttonUp;
    public static JButton buttonDown;
    public static JLabel stage;

    public static void main(String [] args){
        JFrame window = new JFrame("RobotController");
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setSize(200, 200);
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        //add panel to window
        window.add(panel);

        stage = new JLabel("");
        stage.setBounds(85, 65, 50, 35);
        panel.add(stage);

        buttonLeft = new JButton("←");
        buttonLeft.setBounds(10, 65, 50, 35);
        //buttonLeft.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panel.add(buttonLeft);

        buttonRight = new JButton("→");
        buttonRight.setBounds(130, 65, 50, 35);
        panel.add(buttonRight);


        buttonUp = new JButton("↑");
        buttonUp.setBounds(70, 25, 50, 35);
        panel.add(buttonUp);

        buttonDown = new JButton("↓");
        buttonDown.setBounds(70, 105, 50, 35);
        panel.add(buttonDown);

        window.addKeyListener(new Main());

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            buttonLeft.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            System.out.println("Left");
            stage.setText("Left");
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            buttonRight.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            System.out.println("Right");
            stage.setText("Right");
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            buttonUp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            System.out.println("Up");
            stage.setText("Up");
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            buttonDown.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            System.out.println("Down");
            stage.setText("Down");
        }
    }  

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JButton lol = new JButton();
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            buttonLeft.setBackground(lol.getBackground());
            stage.setText("");
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            buttonRight.setBackground(lol.getBackground());
            stage.setText("");
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            buttonUp.setBackground(lol.getBackground());
            stage.setText("");
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            buttonDown.setBackground(lol.getBackground());
            stage.setText("");
        }




    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Is this really running on a raspberry-Pi?

Answer (score 1):

`KeyListener` is well known for been picky about when it would generate `KeyEvent`s. A `KeyListener` will only generate `KeyEvent`s when the component it is registered to IS focusable and HAS focus.

Adding a KeyListener directly to a window makes it even more difficult, as there can be any number of components between the window and the use, which can steal focus.

Instead, you should be using the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which allows you to control the level of focus required to generate key events

Comment: @MarkJeronimus KeyListener isn't the only problem, which component actually gets focus when the window first opens is platform dependent...